# Are IAP's single-use consumables limited to games?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, appstore-approval

Are single-use consumables limited to games?

All the example I've seen are stuff like gems, or other types of currencies used to purchase items in games.

**Can this model be implemented in other types of apps?** For example, purchase 50 tokens, use 10 tokens to start a conversation with a life coach.

In a related note, **can features such as messaging and video conference be monetized?** For example, use 10 tokens start a chat conversation, use 20 tokens to start a chat conversation with video conference capability.

I am looking specifically at this guideline:

> 3.2.2 (ii) Monetizing built-in capabilities provided by the hardware or operating system, such as Push Notifications, the camera, or the gyroscope; or Apple services, such as Apple Music access or iCloud storage.

I have read the IAP guidelines but still cannot answer these questions.

Comment: Both concepts / ideas sound absolutely valid, look at Tinder for example, no game, but in app consumables. There is nothing in the specs restricting the usage to games.

Answer (score 1):

No, consumable IAPs are not limited to games. You can use them for any purpose that makes sense in your app.